# Instalación de paquete ggflags sin Internet

Tags: r, ggplot2, librería

necesito instalar el paquete ggflags en una máquina con windows 10 no conectada a Internet.

Tengo instalado el paquete en una máquina con Internet, funciona correctamente, instale el paquete desde GitHub, pero necesito instalarlo en una que no puede conectarse a Internet

lo baje mediante

```
devtools::install_github("ellisp/ggflags")
```

### intentos

utilice

```
remotes::install_local ("C:/Users/Hernan_R/Documents/GitHub/ggflags")
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

> byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in ggproto("GeomInteractiveFlag", GeomFlag, default_aes = ggiraph:::add_default_interactive_aes(GeomFlag), : object 'interactive_geom_parameters' not found

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Tengo instalado el paquete en una máquina con Internet,  funciona correctamente, instale el paquete desde GitHub,  pero necesito instalarlo en una que no puede conectarse a Internet

Comment: Y como lo instalaste?

Comment: devtools::install_github("ellisp/ggflags")

Comment: hola @hernanrodriguez hice una investigacion para ver de que se trataba y he editado tu pregunta con lo que creo que es el contexto. en base a ello encontre esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989027/how-to-install-a-package-from-a-download-zip-file lamento no ser de mas ayuda ya que no manejo ese lenguaje. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @RuslanLópez revisare lo indicado en estas repuestas, creoque es lo que buscaba

Comment: @RuslanLópez utilice remotes::install_local ("C:/Users/Hernan_R/Documents/GitHub/ggflags") y me sale el siguiente error: ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in ggproto("GeomInteractiveFlag", GeomFlag, default_aes = ggiraph:::add_default_interactive_aes(GeomFlag),  : 
  object 'interactive_geom_parameters' not found